# Universally usable macro definitions with literal UTF-8 content

Tags: pdftex, input-encodings, strings

Since UTF-8 is the default input encoding, it should be straigthforward to use literal Unicode characters
in macro arguments,e.g.

```
\newcommand*{\regards}{Grüße}
```

This fails, if the macro is defined in an external file (a package, say) but utilised in a document that uses a legacy *input encoding* (e.g. "latin1").

A workaround is to wrap the string in an
input-encoding switch:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\ifdefined\UnicodeEncodingName
\else
  \usepackage{lmodern}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\fi

\newcommand*{\UTFviiiInputEncodingName}{utf8}
\newcommand*{\UTFviiiInput}[1]{%
  \ifdefined \inputencoding
    \ifx\inputencodingname\UTFviiiInputEncodingName
      #1
    \else
      \let\PreviousInputEncodingName\inputencodingname
      \inputencoding{utf8}#1\inputencoding{\PreviousInputEncodingName}
    \fi
  \else
    #1
  \fi
}  

\begin{document}

Let's define and use an example:
\newcommand{\regardsI}{\UTFviiiInput{Grüße}}
regards -> \regardsI.

Without \verb|\protect|, a section heading
using the macro fails in the ToC:

\section{Freundliche \protect\regardsI}

We also need to think about indices, glossaries,
footnotes\footnote{Viele \regardsI}, hyperref, \ldots

\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

For use in moving arguments, should the wrapper macro be *robust* or *expandable* or something inbetween?

I would prefer "partial early expasion" down to LICRs, so that the `\meaning` of the example macro
became `macro:->Gr\" u\ss e`.

The intended use case is macros for localized captions and month names in the ``greek.ldf'' Babel *language definition file*.

Comment: hyperref doesn't like your example at all.

Comment: This is all quite a large run time cost, I think I would just use utf8 in the source and expand to LICR during the package build. If you use l3build a simple lua replace function would do the job

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: The idea would be to expand to LICR once (when loading the package or language definition file), but only with documents using legacy encodings. With Xe/LuaTeX or input-encoding utf8, the macro should keep containing the literal characters.

Comment: as the utf8 inputenc definitions are (now) `\protected` definitions it's a little tricky to expand them once, but possible of course.

Comment: simplest is just to put `\ifx\inputencodingname\UTFviiiInputEncodingName\else \message{21st century}\stop\fi` at the top of the file :-)

Comment: In an ideal world, there were a helper function in the LaTeX kernel or in Babel (where it may replace the need to define all auto-strings twice: in UTF8 and LICR formats).

Comment: @G.Milde yes, I have some code somewhere.....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle in hyperref. But I would simply go the "sorry, utf8 required" way.

Comment: The "UTF8 required" way would break backwards compatibility of the Babel ldf file. And there is currently no rollback mechnism for `*.ldf` files.

Comment: yes I know that it breaks backwards compatibility. But I wouldn't care. It is much less trouble to tell user to convert the files to utf8 and be done with it.

Comment: It's not entirely straightforward converting files to utf8 and it is easy to really screw up by doing not-immediately-obviously-but-actually-incredibly-stupid things.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I would like to use this "some code somewhere" --- if it is not more complicated than replicating the ca. 80 auto-string definitions in babel-greek.

Comment: @G.Milde as Ulrike says we updated hyperrefs pdf bookmark command to cope with the \protected utf8 characters in recent latex see hyperref.dtx %
% \subsubsection{Support for UTF-8 input encoding}
%
%    After |\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}| there are macros that
%    expect the UTF-8 octets as arguments. Therefore we can
%    calculate the PDF octal sequences directly. Because the
%    PDF format is limited to UCS-2, conversion macros are
%    needed for UTF-8 sequences with two and three octets only.
%
%    This calculation must be done in an expandable context,